# Modulus differentiation

Tags: derivatives, modular-arithmetic

For a Java project, I need to find a way to compute the derivate of a modulus function like
$$f(x) = g(x) \pmod{h(x)}$$
for any value of $x$.

I know that the modulus function is discontinuous.
If there is no way to compute that, do you have any suggestion to obtain a coherent result?

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)=g(x) |h(x)|$? or modular arithmetic like $p = q \mod r$

Comment: Or do you mean $$f(x):=g(x)-\left\lfloor {g(x)\over h(x)}\right\rfloor h(x)$$ with $h>0$ ?

Comment: I mean like $p = q\ mod\ r$ $$f(x) = g(x)\ mod\ h(x)$$

Comment: Does not seem the most possible thing. But I think you have to directly substitute what a modular function or notation do in terms of some specific function. And maybe try derive it from first principle.

Answer (score 2):

You can write $f$ as :
$$f(x) = g(x)-\left\lfloor\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}\right\rfloor h(x)  = g(x)-k(x) h(x) $$
With $k(x)=\left\lfloor\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}\right\rfloor$ being a piece-wise constant function. Thus your derivative will only exist on the intervals where $k$ is constant (and where $k'=0$) :
$$f'(x) = g'(x)-\left\lfloor\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}\right\rfloor h'(x)  = g'(x)-k(x) h'(x) $$
On the points of discontinuity of $k$ (ie between the intervals), the derivative cannot be defined, which is normal since the function is discontinuous.

EDIT :

Apparently you want to apply modulo in the polynomial ring, but then your problem is not clearly explained then. Are your polynomial with constant coefficient ? If yes, then you have :
$$f(X) = g(X)-q(X) h(X)$$
Where $q$ is the quotient of $g$ by $h$, and $f$ is the remainder. By using Euclid algorithm, you can compute the remainder $f$, then derive it like usual. More info here on polynomial division : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division

If however you have non constant polynomial, things get more tricky, if the coefficient are all continuous function, I suspect you will have "piece wise defined" quotient and remainder, but I'm not sure it will be easy to compute where and how their value changes.

Comment: Are you sure that's $k'(x)$ is always equals to $0$ ? For example, i have $$ f(x) = g(x)\ mod\ h(x)$$ with $$g(x) = x^4+2x' 3-4x^2+x-3$$ and $$h(x) = x^2+3x+1$$ the result of $\lfloor \frac{g(x)}{h(x)} \rfloor$ is $8x-1$ and the derivate of $8x-1$ is not equal to $0$.

Comment: That's because the modulo operator you are using is not defined on reals, but on a polynomial ring. The floor operator as usually defined applied to a continuous function gives you a constant function. Now if you are working with polynomials it's a different story, but this I could not have guessed from your original post. For future reference, use $X$ rather than $x$ if you talk about polynomial (by convention $x$ it rather used for real values)

Comment: If it's what you want, it might be useful to have a library for symbolic mathematics. Now I never did scientific programming in Java, but you'll probably be able to find something on google.

Comment: Thank's for your answer, I have found nothing on google for now... and yes, i'm working with Java on which the modulo operator is defined for the double !

Comment: So what you want is polynomial modulo ? (double modulo is real modulo, right ?). I don't think you will find it in the standard library of Java. Several symbolic library are referenced here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574949/is-there-something-like-sympy-for-java 
Besides you'll most certainly also find a derivation operator in those library.